# Error "Can not find appropriate suite scope for class" when running 'phpspec describe'

Tags: laravel, phpspec

I'm trying to get phpspec running with Laravel, following [this video](https://laracasts.com/lessons/phpspec-laravel-and-refactoring)

I install it ok with composer, and add an alias, but when I run:

```
  phpspec describe Shipping'
```

I get an error:

```
 [RuntimeException] 
 Can not find appropriate suite scope for class `Shipping`.
```

Answer (score 3):

check namespace in your composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
      "Acme\\":"app/Acme"
    }
```

and of-course

```
composer dumpautoload
```

and

in phpspec.yml file

```
suites:
 acme_suites:
  namespace: Acme
```

phpspec describe Acme\Shipping

Comment: You should use forward slash when describe the Spec: 
phpspec describe Acme/Shipping